# Android button focused state working but pressed not?

Tags: java, android, button, fragment, selector

In my app, I am using a custom button with selector states. The unpressed and focused states are working just fine, though the pressed state won't work. Any ideas? The on click listener is implemented in a fragment if that means anything.

Here is my selector code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/participants_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/participants_pressed"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/participants_unpressed" />
</selector>
```

And here is my java code:

```
Button participantsSelector = new Button(getActivity());
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300,300);
participantsSelector.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_participants);
participantsSelector.setLayoutParams(lp);
participantsSelector.setClickable(true);
participantsSelector.setOnClickListener(this);
participantsGrid.addView(participantsSelector);
```

Comment: remove the `state_focused`

Answer (score 0):

Button are only pressed when the user has the finger on them. You can use ToggleButton if you want two distinct states.

For your drawable :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" /> //currently pressed turning the toggle on
<item android:state_pressed="true" /> //currently pressed turning the toggle off
<item android:state_checked="true" /> //not pressed default checked state
<item /> //default non-pressed non-checked
```

Answer (score 0):

With your XML and the Button you already have, I wonder... what if you programmatically toggle state in the listener?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if(button.isSelected()) {
      button.setSelected(false);
    } else {
      button.isSelected(true);
    }
  }
});
```